# How to write regex to match only one digit at end of pattern?

Tags: regex

My field is supposed to be in the format of A111-1A1, but my regex allows the very last number to be more than one digit (eg. A111-1A1212341). How do I fix this?

Below is the regex I am currently using.

```
var validchar = /^[A-Z](([0-9]{3})+\-)[0-9][A-Z][0-9]+$/;
```

Comment: Please specify the required pattern a little better.

Comment: var validchar = /^[A-Z](([0-9]{3})+\-)[0-9][A-Z][0-9]+$/; Strange, I don't know how I posted the wrong regex in my first post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `+` at the end of your pattern. That is what allows for more than one numeric at the end.

```
var validchar = /^A-Z[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/;
```

However, your pattern otherwise doesn't look right to do what you say you want. Is that really the exact pattern you are using?

Comment: Thanks, it was the "+" that was the problem.

Comment: Ahhh; I see your update with the real original pattern now. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var validchar = /^[A-Z][0-9]{3}\-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/;
```

Or remove the + from the end of your regex

```
var validchar = /^A-Z[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the final `+` from your regex:

```
var validchar = /^[A-Z]([0-9]{3})+\-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/;
```